# Apply 2 Styles within Text[]

Tags: graphics, text

Please consider :

```
aboveBox[info_, colors_] := 
 Graphics[{colors, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {26, 3}], 
   Text[Style[info, 18, Bold, Black, TextAlignment -> Center], 
        {26, 3}/2]}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: aboveBox[] output]

Now I would like to have a second bit of text aside, with a different style.

I know I could use 2 `Text[]`s, but I then struggle with the alignment.

Is there a way to have two bits of text with different Style within the same `Text[]`

Example of desired output :

[image: aboveBox[] with text in different styles]

Comment: `Row[{Style["subject ",Black,10],Style["AK6",Pink,18]}]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `Row` to build up the text to be shown:

```
aboveBox[info_, colors_] := 
 Graphics[{colors, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {26, 3}], 
   Text[Row[{Style["subject", 12, Bold, Black, 
       TextAlignment -> Center], 
      Style[info, 18, Bold, Red, TextAlignment -> Center]}], {26, 3}/
     2]}, ImageSize -> 300]

aboveBox["AK6", LightBlue]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can do without `TextAlignment -> Center`.

Comment: @Spartacus Probably.  It was present in the original code, and I just didn't bother to remove it.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility which may even give you help for the next time is, to look how Mathematica represents the two-colored Text you want. So go into a notebook and format the text as you like it with the font-menu. For instance

[image]

Now, while still being in this cell you press `Ctrl+Shift+E` and you get (I commented the unimportant stuff out):

```
 (*Cell[BoxData[*)
 RowBox[{
  StyleBox["subject",
   FontVariations->{"Underline"->True},
   FontColor->GrayLevel[0]], 
  StyleBox[":",
   FontVariations->{"Underline"->True},
   FontColor->GrayLevel[0]], 
  StyleBox["AK6",
   FontWeight->"Bold",
   FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]}] (*], 
 "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.5377269466224403`*^9, 3.537726946623592*^9}}] *)
```

These are some of the low-level boxes used by Mathematica to set any expression you use in the front-end. The good thing is, you can use this directly in your code if you wrap this with `DisplayForm`

```
aboveBox[info_, colors_] := 
 Graphics[{colors, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {26, 3}], Text[
    DisplayForm@
     RowBox[{StyleBox["subject", 
        FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}, 
        FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]], 
       StyleBox[":", FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}, 
        FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]], 
       StyleBox[info, FontWeight -> "Bold", 
        FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]}]
    , {26, 3}/2]}, ImageSize -> 300]

aboveBox["DrX", LightBlue]
```

[image]

Btw: Don't forget `Inset` which can be used for this purpose too. Since `Inset` can handle general objects you want to place inside a graphics, it seems it is more general and may become handy sometime.

Comment: Boxes...  Ugh...